# C# OpenTK on OSX: GLSL Error, Version is not supported

Tags: macos, opengl, opentk

I am running Mac OSX 10.9.2 natively and tried to run the following C# code: http://pastebin.com/b6GpxjuL

I am using Xamarin Studio with OpenTK to compile the code, but as soon as I start it, I am getting these errors in the console:

```
[0:] 
[0:] ERROR: 0:2: '' :  version '410' is not supported
ERROR: 0:4: 'layout' : syntax error syntax error


[0:] 
[0:] ERROR: 0:2: '' :  version '410' is not supported
```

I already tried different versions for the shaders, but I am always getting the error "version XXX is not supported".
A render window with a triangle shows up nevertheless, though without the shaders compiled it's not displayed correctly.

I already checked Apple's compatibility list and my machine supports version 4.1 (GeForce 650): https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

OpenTK 1.1 is using Carbon, which does not support OpenGL > 2.1. For OpenGL 3.x/4.x you have two options:

- enable the SDL2 backend by copying `libSDL2.dylib` from `opentk/Dependencies/x86` to your application directory
- compile the latest [development version from github](https://github.com/opentk/opentk)

OpenTK 1.1.2 will support OpenGL 3.x/4.x out of the box. This will be officially released in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code but use the 'GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible' which works, along with GraphicsMode.Default. I found that glGetString(GL_VERSION) gave me 4.1 and if I used any context other than this (even say 4.0) it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

What does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)` say? Actually you should use the GLSL version which the last call will tell you.